# I want to select the latest 7 days of data using the Time column

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL SERVER Table with Time and other columns. The data coming in the Time column as `Dec 23 2019 7:13PM`

I want to select the latest 7 days of data using the Time column. I tried below but no luck and getting an error.

**Query**:

```
Select [SQL Instance]
      ,[Database]
      ,[Target Login Name], [Time] from [dbo].[SQLLoginsAlerts] where Time >= SELECT DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE());
```

**Error**:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Column information**:

DATA TYPE: nvarchar(50)

How data is coming into the column:

e.g:

```
declare @Time nvarchar(50)
SET  @Time =  GETDATE()
INSERT INTO (@Time)
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is pretty good about converting date/time values with no format string.  So this should work:

```
where convert(datetime, Time) >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

The caveat is that you might have bad values in the data.  To prevent problems with that, use `try_convert()`:

```
where try_convert(datetime, Time) >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

You can see the bad values by using:

```
select time
from SQLLoginsAlerts
where try_convert(datetime, time) is null and time is not null;
```

And after all this, **fix your data**!  Do not store date/time values as strings.  The built-in data types are there for a reason.